# Linked link function won't put the max item at the end of the list, as intended

Tags: c, linked-list

I have a linked list and I have to make sure that whatever the max number of the list is, I put it at the end of the linked list. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Can someone please explain?

```
void moveAllMaxAtEnd(list A) {
    int max=0;
    link tmp=A->first;
    link curr=tmp->next;
    int i,count=0;
    while(curr!=NULL){          //This first while is where I find the max item
        if(curr->item>=max){
            max=curr->item;
            count++;
        }
        else{
            curr=curr->next;
        }
     }
     link prev=A->first;
     link curr1=prev->next;
     link tmp1;
     while(curr1->next!=NULL){   //In this loop I am trying to put the 
         if(curr1->item==max){   //max items at the end.
            prev->next=curr1->next;
            tmp1=prev->next;
            prev->next=curr1->next;
            curr1->next=tmp1;
         }
         else{
             prev=prev->next;
             curr1=curr1->next;
         }
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work although I haven't tested it. If it's homework, please do not read the answer today (learn from yourself will help you more !).

Do a little drawing of your list elements and see the link behaviour. You will see immediately the problem with this method.

**My drawing example**

[image: list drawing]

**Correction (do not read immediately)**

```
void moveAllMaxAtEnd(list A) {
    int max=0;
    link tmp=A->first;
    link curr=tmp->next;
    int i,count=0;
    while(curr!=NULL){          //This first while is where I find the max item
        if(curr->item>=max){
            max=curr->item;
            count++; //not used, may be cleaned up
        }
        //else{  //else is not needed the code would be executed in next loop anyway
        curr=curr->next;
        //}
     }
     link prev=A->first;
     link curr1=prev->next;
     link tmp1;
     while(curr1->next!=NULL){   //In this loop I am trying to put the 
         if(curr1->item==max){   //max items at the end.
            prev->next=curr1->next;
            tmp1=curr1; // not prev->next;
            // prev->next=curr1->next; cur1 has not changed you re-do exactly the same
            // curr1->next=tmp1;
            curr1->next=NULL; //it will be the last element
         }
         else{
             prev=prev->next;
             curr1=curr1->next;
         }
     }
     curr1->next = tmp1; //add the element we cut before
}
```

Comment: is there a way that I can just make it move it one node over until it gets to the end or do I have to do it like that?

Comment: @vic There are hundreds of ways to do everything ;) May be try to group your 2 while loop and move nodes one by one to sort completely the list would be a good idea. Do drawings and if it's not enough to make it work, do more drawings.

Answer (score 0):

problem (1)

```
link tmp=A->first;
link curr=tmp->next;
int i,count=0;
while(curr!=NULL){          //This first while is where I find the max item
    if(curr->item>=max){
        max=curr->item;
```

The first element is excluded. (No problem if the first element is a dummy.)

problem (2)

```
prev->next=curr1->next;//curr1 cut off
tmp1=prev->next;
prev->next=curr1->next;//Processing is a duplicate. meaningless.
curr1->next=tmp1;//==> curr1->next= prev->next ==> curr1->next= curr1->next;meaningless.
```

Specific process does not exist.

fix like this:
(Note:The first element is processing if It's not the dummy. Change is easy)

```
void moveAllMaxAtEnd(list A){
    if(!A || !A->first || !A->first->next)
        return;

    link prev = A->first;
    link curr = prev->next;
    int max = prev->item;

    while(curr != NULL){//This first while is where I find the max item
        if(curr->item >= max){
            max = curr->item;
        }
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    link last = prev;

    prev = NULL;
    curr = A->first;
    link max_list = NULL;

    while(curr->next != NULL){
        if(curr->item == max){
            link cut = curr;
            curr = curr->next;
            if(prev){
                prev->next = cut->next;
            } else {
                A->first = cut->next;
            }
            cut->next = max_list;
            max_list = cut;
        } else {
            prev = curr;
            curr = curr->next;
        }
    }
    last->next = max_list;
}
```